# While loop with multiple conditions

Tags: python

So my while loop just keeps looping even when it shouldn't, if there is only 1 condition the loop works and then proceeds to the next lines of code but when I add the OR statement it wont work, I'm sure it's something very silly but I'm only a beginner and have tried researching this.

```
Choice = input("What would you like to do? New Game, Continue, or Quit?").upper()
while Choice != "NEW GAME" or Choice != "QUIT":
    print ("That input was invalid, please try again.")
    Choice = input("What would you like to do? New Game, Continue, or Quit? ").upper()
    if Choice == "QUIT":
        quit()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition

```
Choice != "NEW GAME" or Choice != "QUIT"
```

will always be `True`. Any value of `Choice` will be either not `"NEW GAME"` or not `"QUIT"`. Instead, use:

```
Choice != "NEW GAME" and Choice != "QUIT":
```

Comment: That was simple.... I always thought and meant both conditions needed to be true, but that worked, thanks :)

Comment: That's exactly what `and` means. But the conditions in this case are `!=`, not `=`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for

`while Choice not in ["New Game", "Continue", "Quit"]`

or better to allow for alternative capitalization:

`while Choice.upper() not in ["NEW GAME", "CONTINUE", "QUIT"]`

Also please uncapitalize the variable `Choice`. When other Python programmers see a variable that starts with a capital letter they assume at first that it is a class name.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want a `and` there, not a `or`…

Because `Choice` can't be at the same time **not** different from `"NEW GAME"` and from `"QUIT"`. In other words, your loop condition is always `True` whatever the value of `Choice` is.